# Running pandas.io.gbq from a cron job

Tags: python, pandas, cron, google-bigquery

I've put together a script to query a local API and also Google BigQuery, where I am using pandas.io.gbq to pass queries to BigQuery and return them back to pandas dataframes. For example.

```
   raw_page_id_date  = gbq.read_gbq(query, project_id=project_id, dialect='standard')

   gbq.to_gbq(raw_page_id_date, destination_table='ohalloranb.raw_page_id_date', project_id='tmg-data-science-dev', verbose=True, reauth=False, if_exists='replace', private_key=None)
```

The script runs correctly when I run it from the command line - it queries the API and BigQuery and dumps out the output as expected. However, when I try to run it as a cron job, I hit problems. The first part - querying the local API runs without issues. However, it crashed when it hits the BigQuery queries:

```
   raw_page_id_date  = gbq.read_gbq(query, project_id=project_id, dialect='standard')

   TypeError: read_gbq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dialect'
```

Is this an authentication issue, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the cron job is using a different version of `pandas` than what you are using from the command line. The `dialect` option to `read_gbq` was [added in version 0.19.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13615). You might want to try having your cron job print the version number and--if it's less than 0.19.0--change the job to use a more recent version instead.

Comment: That indeed was the problem: cron was using the base install of Python on my machine, and not the version with the upgraded version of pandas.

A facepalm moment, but it's all working as it should now.